# Sample random high-dimensional rotation, of bounded angle

Tags: linear-transformations, lie-groups, rotations, random, sampling

I want to sample uniformly at random from all $n\times n$ orthogonal matrices $M$, subject to two requirements:

1. $M$ is an [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix).  Loosely speaking, it represents a rotation (or rotation with reflection).
2. $Mx$ is at angle $\le \theta$ from $x$, for all $x$, where $\theta$ is a fixed constant.  Equivalently, $x^\top Mx \le c x^\top x$ for all $x$, where $c=\cos^{-1} \theta$ is a fixed constant.

Loosely speaking, these matrices represent rotation matrices that rotate by at most a bounded amount.

Is there an algorithm or method to sample uniformly at random from the set of such matrices?

I'm working in high dimensions, where $n$ is large (say 1000; not 2 or 3).  My application is probably too esoteric to be of general interest; it relates to generating new unit vectors that are "similar" to existing unit vectors, with similarity measured by angle / cosine distance.  Rejection sampling seems ineffective in high-dimensional spaces, as the proportion of orthogonal matrices that satisfy the second constraint is exponentially small, so it would require exponentially many draws from $O(n)$ to find a single such matrix.

Comment: Have you tried generating random anti symmetric matrices and exponentiating?

Comment: @user619894, No!  That hadn't occurred to me at all.  Interesting.  How does that enforce the limit on the angle?

Comment: The eigenvalues of the antisymmetric matrix determine the angles of the rotation it exponentiates to; if they're bounded then so are the angles. For example $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & \theta \\ - \theta & 0 \end{array} \right]$ exponentiates to a rotation by $\theta$. Also, it doesn't sound to me like your application really needs *uniform* samples, maybe just "reasonably uniform" samples, in which case you wouldn't have to worry so much about whatever distribution you'd be using to generate random antisymmetric matrices; is that right?

Comment: a lazy way to enforce the constraint is by rejection

Comment: @user619894, I've revised the question to explain why rejection sampling doesn't work.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I'd like a uniform sample (or one that is close to uniform, where the error can be made arbitrarily small), so it sounds like that approach is not going to be sufficient.  It's not clear to me how to put the pieces of the exponentiation idea together: I would need to generate a random antisymmetric matrix with bounded eigenvalues, then exponentiate it?

Comment: Yes (equivalently, since skew-symmetric matrices are normal, it suffices to bound their operator norm). But if you really want uniformity it's unclear what distribution you'd need to ensure the result is uniform among rotations satisfying the angle bound.